# export the table data as CSV format

Tags: smartgwt

in my web project there is no any servlet and other things. only pure core java with gwt packages.

In client side I have a ListGrid with some data. if want to export as .csv format, what should I have to do?

here I gone through samples and blogs are through servlet but I dont have any servlet at all. 
how to save as .csv format

Thanks

Comment: Which SmartGWT version (number and type of license) do you use?

Comment: smartGWT version is 2.4